# Former Bootable Thumb drive preventing Raspberry Pi from booting up

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb-drive

I have a problem with a 64 GB USB Thumb Drive. I used it for a CentOS bootable drive. I've tried the following things, but the drive stops my Raspberry 4 (Raspian Lite) from booting up. When I take the thumb drive out of the Raspberry Pi it boots fine.

I've tried completely wiping and partitioning the drive …

I've used Gparted on my Ubuntu PC, I ran GParted. Selected the 64 GB USB stick (/dev/sdb) in the top-right menu. Delete all partitions. Create a very large partition. Clicked confirm.

Also, I tried:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

Command (m for help):d
```

After reading a post, I also tried:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=1
```

I also used Windows 10 to format, and partition, the drive.

None of these things will stop the drive, causing the Raspberry Pi 4 (Raspian Lite) from not being able to boot up.

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you've effectively wiped the drive, and it still prevents Pi from booting? Try booting without the drive inserted, then insert the drive ... see what is output in `dmesg`

Comment: @Jaromanda I booted the Pi, then inserted the USB Drive, ran `dmesg` and then the Pi started to reboot by itself, and of course with the USB Drive inserted it couldn't boot up. To be honest I don't really know what to look for in `dmesg`

Comment: perhaps the thumb drive is (electrically) faulty - though, as it didn't seem to cause issues in other systems perhaps it's just a power issue with the pi - do you have a decent power supply for the pi?

Comment: @JaromandaX Using `dmesg` I see `[    7.301110] hwmon hwmon1: Undervoltage detected!` so maybe there is an issue with the power supply.

Comment: Yap. My RasPi 4 was throwing the same errors with most external drives with the official PSU. The only way around was to buy a more powerful unit.

Comment: I was using a USBC cable plugged into a PC USB port for power because I couldn't find my power supply for the RPi. I had another look tonight and found it, problem solve!

Comment: Thanks for the help @JaromandaX